# How to rename a file for a specific maven build profile

Tags: maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I've got changes to my web.xml config file that need to stay local-only since Google-App-Engine chokes on them when we try to use them, and they're really only needed for development purposes.

How can I make maven copy my `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web_local.xml` to be `web.xml` in the target `WEB-INF` directory?

I looked into maven-assembly-plugin, but that didn't provide a way to give a name to the ouput file (plus it seemed specifically for building .jar files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [webXml](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webXml) property of the maven-war-plugin plugin configuration to point to custom web.xml